Encrypt Response Body with Attribute in ASP.NET
I'm trying to make an Attribute to Encrypt response of an Api.
This is the Attribute Code
public class MyCustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute {
    private MemoryStream responseBody;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
        responseBody = new MemoryStream();
        context.HttpContext.Response.Body = responseBody;
    }

    public override async void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context) {
        responseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (StreamReader sr = new(responseBody)) {
            string actionResult = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
            string j = AesOperation.EncryptString("b14ca5898a4e4133bbce2ea2315a1916", actionResult);
            Console.WriteLine("LLL");
            Console.WriteLine(j);

            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(j);
        }

        base.OnResultExecuted(context);
    }
}

And This is The Api
[HttpGet]
[MyCustomFilter]
public ActionResult<GenericResponse<EnumDto>> Read() => repository.ReadAppSettings();

And Here is the Error I'm getting
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HN5FN3JH41NQ", Request id "0HN5FN3JH41NQ:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length mismatch: too few bytes written (0 of 12847).


Is your " AesOperation.EncryptString" returning a base64 string? If not try to encrypt it one more time with a base64 algorithm.

What are you trying to protect against? The response is already encrypted by default through HTTPS, using asymmetric cryptography and far stronger encryption than what's shown here. It can easily be configured on the server to use even stronger encryption.

Responses aren't text either, especially after encryption and/or compression. And JSON responses definitely don't use text/plain. async void is a critical bug too, which will certainly break this code. async void methods can't be awaited, which means the server will just go on and complete the response before ReadToEndAsync has a chance to complete

The issue you're having is likely because of how HttpResponseStream (a type internal to AspNetCore) behaves - no read, no seek, only write. The underlying type also seems to behave differently, but I didn't go that deep (see here if you want to know more).
Anyway, this code seeks to save the original stream, replace it with a MemoryStream (much like you did), get the string from said MemoryStream and then WRITE it to the original HttpResponseStream, re-adding it in the end to the HttpContext.Response.Body:
public class MyCustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private Stream responseBody;
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //changed
        responseBody = context.HttpContext.Response.Body;

        context.HttpContext.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;
        string str;

        var ms1 = new MemoryStream();
        context.HttpContext.Response.Body.CopyTo(ms1);
        ms1.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader sr = new(ms1))
        {
            str = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //use your own implementation of encryption to get a string and feed it to the GetBytes method below, I chose to give a base64 string
        (encrypted, byte[] key, byte[] iv) = Encrypt(str);

        responseBody.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted))).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        base.OnResultExecuted(context);
    }
}

This will do what you want it to, however it's not pretty - you should only if you really need to encrypt the response.

1.I think that the mistakes cause by using MemoryStream because I only write "context.HttpContext.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();" and it reported the error as your code.
2.context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(j) can't run in the OnResultExecuted function.you can use it in the OnResultExecuting function.
3.I write an example for you .I hope this can help you.
1). MyCustomFilter.cs
public class MyCustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private MemoryStream responseBody = new MemoryStream();

    public override  void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //responseBody = new MemoryStream();
        //context.HttpContext.Response.Body = responseBody;

        Stream originalBody = context.HttpContext.Response.Body;
        try
        {
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Body = memStream;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Body = originalBody;
        }

    }

    public override async void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        //responseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (StreamReader sr = new(responseBody))
        {
            string actionResult = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
            //string j = AesOperation.EncryptString("b14ca5898a4e4133bbce2ea2315a1916", actionResult);
            //Console.WriteLine("LLL");
            //Console.WriteLine(j);

            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/string";
            await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Write Something in Filter");
        }

        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }

}

2).Controller.cs
[HttpGet]
[MyCustomFilter]
public ActionResult Read() =>
     Content($"- {nameof(ResponseHeaderController)}.{nameof(Read)}");

3). The results is:

